# Facebook app iframe + JS Facebook.init + IE7 + Flash9 sandbox error

Tags: javascript, flash, facebook

During facebook iframe application integration I ask for publish permissions - I have HTML which loads JS Connect library and asks for permission dialog..

```
  FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function(){ 
        FB.Facebook.init("_MY_API_KEY", "MY_PATH/xd_receiver.htm");
        FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog('publish_stream');
```

However in IETester with IE7 i get weird errors

```
SecurityError: Error #2060: Security sandbox violation: ExternalInterface caller http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zDVWA/hash/bqv7w2jc.swf cannot access ..(MY APP PAGE)

    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_initJS()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/addCallback()
    at flashutils::PostMessage()
    at XdComm()
```

As far as i understand xd file is intended for flash proxy that uses this ExternalInterface to communicate with facebook and show dialog. After i click OK, everything seems to work further.

Can anyone clarify what can cause this?

Comment: I have noticed the same issue in IE Tester.  Thanks for posting this here.

Answer (score 1):

IETester isn't perfect, simply because it cannot fully emulate a proper IE environment.  When things get tricky, it starts to give weird errors.  And there isn't much trickier than a cross-domain Facebook iframe application.

I would find a real installation of IE7 and check if the problem exists there.  If it doesn't, it's probably not worth your time.  Microsoft provides a [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) application that is excellent for this kind of thing, as well as many [XP and Vista test images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) containing various versions of IE.  They are large downloads, but I highly recommend them over IETester.